# How to run a for loop with variable range?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I want to have a Python program like--

```
for i in range(r):
    if (i==2):
        #change r in some way
```

which will run the loop for the new range r, after it gets modified in the if statement.

Even if I change r after the if statement,the for loop runs for the initial r I gave.This must be happening because range(r) gets fixed in the for statement in the first line itself,and is not affected by change in r later on.

Is there a "simple way" to bypass this?

By "simple" I mean that I don't want to add a counter which counts how many times the loop already ran and how many times it need to run again after changing(specifically increasing) r,or by replacing for loop with a while loop.

Comment: using a while loop and manual counter  is he way to go. you cannot change `r`

Comment: Remember: arguments are passed by value (see “call by object sharing”) in Python. The function is given the _current value_ of r (that is r is evaluated as an expression immediately), and otherwise has no association with the variable use as an argument.

Comment: Instead of using a while loop as the others are saying, I think that there is very likely a better option solving this. Could you extend your post by showing us what it is that you want to achieve? Maybe python indexing can already help you?
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> x[2] = 5
>>> x
[1, 2, 5]

Comment: If one wanted to write some complicated code for such a general request, instead of a simple counter, it might look like this: r = 3; g = my_generator(r); for i in g; if i == 2: g.set_max(42). Where my_generator uses properties to maintain state. Again, and to solidify a point, r was never passed to the my_generator function/constructor: the value 3 was.

Comment: @Dremet I was writing a code for random walk problem without repitition,so i need to check whether the new point was ever visited before or not.If it was visited then,we need to reject that point right?So that step never occured,but initially I started out with a fixed number of steps,so every time I dont use a point,i dont want i to increase at all.


Adding the main code may annoy some users,as it will neither match the title,nor the tags(it will become a scientific computing question).and may also lead to closing of the question as "offtopic".

Comment: @user2864740 Yes,that is exactly what i thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say:

```
for i in range(r):
```

`range(r)` creates a `range` object. It does this only once when the loop is set up initially. Therefore, any changes you make to `r` inside the loop have no effect on the performance of the loop, since it's the `range` object that dictates the number of iterations (it just happens to be initialized with `r`).

Rule of thumb: If you know how many iterations you need in advance, use a `for` loop. If you don't know how many iterations you need, use a `while` loop.

Comment: Thanks,but I already wrote almost everything in the question,u told in this answer.

Comment: I think I should really have to use a while statement anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is possible. However, using a while loop and a manual counter is itself an extremely simple way to do this.

The code will look something like this:

```
i = 0
while i < r:
    if i == 2:
        # Change r in some way
```